# How to resolve symbol 'list'?

Tags: java, android, xml

**Problem**

Currently, I'm trying to use a ListView in my app but when I changed the id of my ListView to `@android:id/list` to fix the previous error of "My content must include a ListView whose id is android.r.id.list" it made it impossible to use `R.id.list` in my `setListAdapter` and gave the new error that I'm trying to get fixed "Cannot resolve symbol 'list'"

**What I've tried**

-invalidating caches

**Code MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cakeapp;
    
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
    
import com.example.cakeapp.R;
    
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] dessert={"Chocolate Mousse",
                "Chocolate Cake",
                "Chocolate Macaroons",
                "Chocolate Cafe Website",
                "Dessert Selection"};
    
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.list, dessert));
    }
}
```

**Code activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.cakeapp">
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CakeApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    
    </application>
    
</manifest>
```

Comment: I think this happen because you not initialize R.id.list as id of listview in java code so program cant identified what type of R.id.list

Comment: @Rifaldi could you give me an example of initializing R.id.list ?

Comment: Should not contain @android:id/list. Mention id's like this @+id/list

Comment: @joby just realize if your problem in your xml not java code. For solving that, just see gobu cooment

Answer (score 0):

You should use **android:id="@+id/list"** instead of **android:id="@android:id/list"**

**Edit your activity_main.xml file to :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```